# Add review stats to flag queue page sidebar

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools

Most tabs on `/review` feature the "review stats" summary table (actually it's on every tab but the list of suggested edits). Could we have that on the 10k flags tab too? I frequently find myself switching to the review page just to check that.

Ideally, I'd like to see it before the "Where should I start" block, but it could be at then end too, after the chat block.